# Scatter plot / tile plot with nested shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to compose this plot in R. Any package would do, including base, lattice, and ggplot.

Each data point contains three subclass groups and is filled independently. It can be a heatmap, `geom_tile`, `geom_point`, etc. Can anyone give me some ideas?

[image]

Comment: I guess geom_tile + geom_point with a squared shape might help

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue what the indented case is, but here is some code to produce a plot that shares some attributes of the example image.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.1

set.seed(42)
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
df$top    <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df$bottom <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df$middle <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], nrow(df), replace = TRUE)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(y = y + 0.25, fill = top), 
            colour = "black", height = 0.5) +
  geom_tile(aes(y = y - 0.25, fill = bottom),
            colour = "black", height = 0.5) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = middle),
            colour = "black", height = 0.5, width = 0.5) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That's great! I spent a whole day investigating it.